# Run and redirect a python script in .htaccess

Tags: python, .htaccess

this is also my first message in StackOverflow so I apologize if I am not describing my problem as well as I should.

I do have a shared hosting and a second level domain, and I am trying to run a python server to be reached on a third level domain at port 5000. Third level domain is simply a folder with its own content and htaccess and since it is a shared hosting any script is killed automatically at midnight. I hence need that at any request to the subdomain

1. the script runs (if it is not running already), and
2. any request at port 5000 is forwarded to the server.

I managed to get point 2 to work with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  http://localhost:5000/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

However, I did not manage to get the script running. I was suggested to use

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +ExecCGI
-----------------%<-----------------
AddHandler fcgid-script .py
-----------------%<-----------------
</IfModule>
```

for scripts outside of the cgibin folder. However it does not work, and literature is not helping understanding how to lunch it and how to combine both of them. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: If your shared hosting platform allows the execution of custom python scripts outside of the designated cgi-bin directory, then surely they should have an explanation on _how_ to do it somewhere in the documentation/FAQ …?

Comment: The important detail in above comment is the leading "If"...

Comment: @CBroe no, they do not unfortunately.

Comment: @arkascha sorry I do not understand what you mean

Comment: Then you should probably go and _ask_. Without knowing what exact kind of setup they are using, this will be trial & error.

Comment: @CBoe, the support was reluctant to give suppot because they want me to move to dedicated server. They also suggested to us the AddHandler but also said that forwarding and Handler cannot work together, and I am not sure this is true.